# Adding parameters optionally to Spring Data JPA Native query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am using Spring Data JPA with native queries like below

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemEntity, Long> {

  @Query(value = "select * from items i where i.category = :itemCategory and i.item_code = :itemCode", nativeQuery = true)
  Page<ItemEntity> search(@Param("itemCategory") String itemCategory, @Param("itemCode") String itemCode, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Now, my use case is

1. It `itemCode` is available, only the item with that code from that category should be returned.
2. But if `itemCode` is not available then all items in that category should be returned.

So the problem with the above category is when `itemCode` is passed as `NULL` no data is returned since it does not match anything. whereas the requirement is it should be ignored.

So is there a way to optionally add a clause to Spring Data JPA native query. I know it is possible with `CriteriaQuery` but can we do something similar for native queries?

Thanks

Comment: Look at using the querydsl extension. That would let you call by either category, code or category and code without having to write any query implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's feasible with native query too. [Very Good explanation here read this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters)

**#Approach1**

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getUser", query = "select u from User u"
            + " where (:id is null or u.id = :id)"    
            + " And :username"

:itemCode is null or i.item_code = :itemCode
```

**#Approach2**

```
# UserDao.java 

  public User getUser(Long id, String usename) {
        String getUser = "select u from user u where u.id " + Dao.isNull(id) 
                       + " And u.username " + Dao.isNull(username);
        Query query = Dao.entityManager.createQuery(getUser);
    }

# Dao.java

   public static String isNull(Object field) {
        if (field != null) {
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    return " = " + "'" + field + "'";
                } else {
                    return " = " + field;
                }

            } else {
                return " is NULL ";
            }
    }
```

[How to handle null value of number type in JPA named query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656632/how-to-handle-null-value-of-number-type-in-jpa-named-query)

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the where condition

```
i.item_code = :itemCode
```

to

```
:itemCode is null or i.item_code = :itemCode
```

Comment: That is not what is being asked.

Comment: sorry, why not ?

Comment: If the passed param is null then ignore it otherwise return matching. Your answer does something else entirely. Essentially, do not add the condition i.item_code = :itemCode if it param is null.